nautilus file manager slowness on 22.04.4: Is this related to terminal issues?
I have noticed that since the issue of the terminal having slowness and delay (documented here) that I've also been seeing Nautilus File Manager issues where I click a folder and it takes a moment to respond.
Are these two things related?
I'm on an AMD R5, 16GB RAM, very low utilization and a fast m.2 drive.
I've been running Ubuntu on this since 18.04 or so and never had any issues.
Now with the terminal issue and 22.04.4 I'm seeing this nautilus unresponsive / slowness also.
The slowness is just a slight delay as you click a folder, you'll see a delay to load.  However, at one point I saw a spinning cursor in Nautilus for a small local folder.
Have others seen this issue too?

I'm experiencing the same issue. It's particularly frustrating when the folder has a large number of files. The search box is also practically unusable, as it takes too long to respond and often causes Nautilus to freeze. Going into Settings > Power and setting "Power Mode" to "Performance" slightly improved the situation here, but the issue remains.

Regarding the terminal slowness issue, a fix was published on June 7th. Try the Software Updater to see if it helps.

When the Mutter fix was finally applied to my OS I also discovered that the Nautilus issues were also resolved.  I've also searched around and noticed that Nautilus does indeed seem to have dependencies on Mutter.   It is likely that the Mutter fix also fixed Nautilus.
